# rosdep initialization without internet

Tags: rosdep, ros-groovy, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a machine that had ROS groovy installed but was not rosdep initialized/updated.  The machine does not have internet access.  I have nodes and nodelets on the machine, and the nodes will run but the nodelets complain about rosdep not being initialized.  rospack profile does not help.

How can I initialize and update rosdep rospack_cache / rosstack_cache correctly?

This [file](https://github.com/TurtleBot-Mfg/turtlebot-ros-groovy/blob/master/debian/postinst) did not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61323/rosdep-initialization-without-internet/) by [Eruditass](https://answers.ros.org/users/3250/eruditass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep init doesn't need a network connection.  It's just a convenience method to add the default rosdep sources.

rosdep update downloads the sources and puts them into your rosdep cache.  You simply need to copy ~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache from a machine which has been updated onto the machine which has not yet.

Alternately you could copy all the source files onto your local harddrive and change the sources.list file to point to the file:/// url then rosdep update will work w/o network, but won't update when external systems update.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xure](https://answers.ros.org/users/14191/xure/) on 2014-04-02**:
@tfoote Hi,tfoote, I've met the "rosdep update"problem recently, can you give me an example of creating "the sources.list file to point to the file:/// url then rosdep update", thanks a lot !!

**Comment by [Xure](https://answers.ros.org/users/14191/xure/) on 2014-04-02**:
@tfoote Hi,tfoote, I've tried your method to change the sources.list file like this"# os-specific listings first
yaml http://localhost:11311/home/xu/sourcelists/osx-homebrew.yaml osx

## generic

yaml http://localhost:11311/home/xu/sourcelists/base.yaml
yaml http://localhost:11311/home/xu/sourcelists/python.yaml
yaml http://localhost:11311/home/xu/sourcelists/ruby.yaml
gbpdistro http://localhost:11311/home/xu/sourcelists/fuerte.yaml fuerte

## newer distributions (Groovy, Hydro, ...) must not be listed anymore, they are being fetched from the rosdistro index.yaml instead". And then, the error comes out "ERROR: unable to process source [http://localhost:11311/home/xu/sourcelists/osx-homebrew.yaml]:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> (http://localhost:11311/home/xu/sourcelists/osx-homebrew.yaml)". Sorry for my poor English, haha...I've no idea then, looking forward to you help, thank you !
```

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-04-03**:
It looks like you've copied the files correctly. But you should be using syntax like "file:///home/xu/sourcelists/base.yaml yaml" no http or port number.

**Comment by [Xure](https://answers.ros.org/users/14191/xure/) on 2014-04-03**:
Thank you very much, I've tried type "rosdep update" for tow days, and it worked at last.....